# sendmail(unix) is able to send mail from any sender mail id without asking for sender mail id password authentication

Tags: unix, smtp, gmail, sendmail

I am trying to use sendmail on an already setup linux box and have following observation.

For a certain domain, any valid email address {say : xyz.com, email: any-valid-mail-id@xyz.com} on receiver side, sendmail is able to successfully send mail to it with any chosen sender email address.The interesting thing is, Sender email can be anything, I have tried multiple. So, the question is how does sendmail verify Sender email authentication?

For ex :

```
SENDER="obama@gmail.com"
TEXT="<html><body><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
<tr><td>Col-1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Col-1-Val</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>"
MAIL_TXT="Subject: Demo Table Mail\nContent-type: text/html\nFrom: $SENDER\nTo: any-valid-mail-id@xyz.com\n\n$TEXT"
echo -e "$MAIL_TXT" | sendmail -t
```

In this case how does sendmail verify that obama@gmail.com wants to send this mail, as it is successfully able to send mail on his behalf without asking for authentication?

Comment: Historically, `sendmail(8)` has never asked for such a thing.  Which version of sendmail is it?  What sort of Linux?

For what it's worth, I consider what you're seeing correct behavior.  But I can see where this might not always be the desired behavior.

Comment: I am concerned about the behavior itself, if it is possible to setup sendmail smtp server without authentication of sender email address, then I can misuse this functionality to send mail to anybody mocking the sender, although actual owner of sender email address have no idea for what purpose his email address being used for? is it not a security vulnerability?

Comment: It was a feature when sendmail was written.  These days, not so much.  Again, which version of sendmail is it?